# how to provide security to the database in websql

Tags: web-sql

my question is how to provide the security to the database in the websql, so that no other person can open the database or modify the database. 
for example:
var db = openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000); creates the database by name AddressBook. so how do i provide the security to the database "AddressBook" so that no other person can open or modify the database "AddressBook".
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't in any browser storage.

You must encrypt before storing to the database. In my approach, I send encryption key for each login user. The keys are changed in rotation with expiring concept.

This is still not very secure. However storing some confidential data should be OK.